# How to Assign IIS APPPOOL\[MyAppPoolName] to Windows Service Log On

Tags: windows-services, iis-7.5

I am trying to assign the IIS APPPOOL[MyAppPoolName] to a Windows Service. I have tried going to the Windows Service Properties > Log On Tab, but have been unable to assign that account to the Windows Service. If I try to Select the User then it comes up with an error.

```
An object (User or Built-in security principal) with the following name cannot be found: "IIS APPPOOL\[MyAppPoolName]...". Check the selected object types and locations for accuracy and ensure that you have typed the object name correctly, or remove this object from the selection.
```

For object types I have both the Built-in security prinicipals and the Users checked off.

If I simply try to type the user account on the Log On screen, it asks for a password. But, no password exists for this user that I know of.

Comment: Maybe Windows Service doesn't allow you to use virtual user accounts (like the ones IIS creates). Probably the better option is to create a dedicated user account and assign it to the Application Pool and Windows Service.

Comment: I used the Network Service, we will see how that goes.